# static function in PHP

Tags: php

If I call public function using scope resolution operator, It is not giving any error.

```
 class Parent_class
{

    public function st_function()
    {
        echo "*************parent class************\n";
    }
}
Parent_class:: st_function();
```

But in PHP documentation on php.net, it ig given that - Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning. Also its given that - Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->
But its not giving any error. Can anyone explain?

```
class Parent_class
{

    public static function st_function()
    {
        echo "*************parent class************\n";
    }
}
Parent_class:: st_function();
$var = new Parent_class();
$var->st_function();
```

Comment: Are you using strict error reporting?

Comment: yes right..when I added error_reporting(E_STRICT),its giving notice as Strict Standards: Non-static method Parent_class::st_function() should not be called statically in D:\wamp\www\test.php on line 103

Answer (score 2):

Static properties can not be accessed through the object, but not static methods.

From the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

> Declaring class properties or methods as static makes them accessible
>   without needing an instantiation of the class. A property declared as
>   static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object (**though
>   a static method can**).

Answer (score 2):

If you activate strict error reporting, you *will* see an error for calling a non-static method statically:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

For the second part, where you call a static method non-statically, that will work because the paragraph in the manual talks about static ***properties***, not methods. You cannot access `Parent_class::static_property` like `Parent_class->static_property`, if it had such a property.

Calling static methods of objects works fine, in that case the `$var->` is just a convenience shorthand for `Parent_class::`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this before your code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```